# Spring - maven - Mi netbeans no reconoce @Controller

Tags: spring-boot, spring, spring-mvc

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy intentando hacer un proyecto de spring maven, pero mi netbeans no reconoce el `@Controller`. Acabo de instalarme el `jdk 18` y el `netbeans 14`.

Cree el proyecto con start.spring.io - Antes estaba usando el `JDK 12` y el `netbeans 12` y funcionaba bien todo en la misma página, luego instale el `JDK 18` y el `netbeans 14` y ya no me carga el mismo proyecto que importe de la pagina de spring:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El proyecto compila perfectamente, el problema aquí es que quiero hacer mi controller para poder entrar a mi index, pero en el intellisense no aparece para importar y si lo hago manualmente tampoco me reconoce.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Netbeans no tiene ni la culpa. Tu proyecto tiene cargadas las dependencias correspondientes?

Comment: Cree el proyecto con https://start.spring.io/ - Antes estaba usando el JDK 12 y el netbeans 12 y funcionaba bien todo en la misma página, luego instale el JDK 18 y el netbeans 14 y ya no me carga el mismo proyecto que importe de la pagina de spring

Comment: Y en spring initializr seleccionaste compatibilidad con java 18?

Comment: 1: https://ibb.co/N7Z6JDk
2: https://ibb.co/QfmNg6y
3: https://ibb.co/JRVhWKk
4: https://ibb.co/7K5LfpL
5:https://ibb.co/VgBqKCQ
6:https://ibb.co/VL9QKR4
Mira

Comment: Pero entonces el proyecto sí compila? Se entiende que no se entiende cuál es el error específico que quieres resolver? La interfaz del plugin funciona bien, el pom queda bien, la anotación tiene un warning pero en la consola sale que te compiló el proyecto.

Comment: https://ibb.co/80Ljwdx
El proyecto compila perfectamente, el problema aquí es que quiero hacer mi controller para poder entrar a mi index, pero en el intellisense no aparece para importar y si lo hago manualmente tampoco me reconoce.
https://ibb.co/68fcCfr

Comment: Por favor, [edit] la pregunta y añade toooooda la info, con eso no se pierde entre los comentarios, a ver si alguien que use Netbeans sabe la respuesta a tu pregunta

Comment: Ya he unido todo.